# file is encrypted or is not a database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, berkeley-db

I have installed Berkeley DB with .msi on oracle site and ADO.NET adapter for SQLite with Design-Time components for Visual Studio. If I run dbsql command from shell and execute each type of operation on Berkeley DB, this works. Even if I create a new project with an edmx file that points to a file sqlite database, this works. Now when I build the project for sqldb adonet and I run the testlinq project, throw the Exception 'file is encrypted or is not a database'. The same error is thrown when I create an edmx file with SQLite Data Provider that have a .db file created with Berkeley DB. What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're opening the right file with the right adapter? I think you're trying to open a berkley-db file as an SQLite database and vice versa.

Comment: No, I'm not sure... I think that I have missed some step, but which one? The adapter of Berkeley is equal to SQLite, but the dll are those of the build of the project adonet on the oracle site. I need to just replace the folder where there are those of SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ADO.NET adapter for Berkeley DB "Berkeley DB dbsql-adodotnet-x.x.x.zip" from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html, that should meet your requirements.